# How to get rid of the message that appers on Chome in Automation: "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software" in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am using Robot Framework to automate.Whenever Chrome gets launched it shows the message; 'Chrome is being controlled by automated test software'. How to get rid of this message?

Comment: It is added by Google and we can't get RID till google want. (anyway it won't impact our automation script)

Comment: thanks for your response but  we can achieve same in selenium using Java..so must be doable in Robot framework as well

Comment: Good to know that raj , could you please share, how you achieved that in Java. we will try to simulate same in robotframework too (May be using Python).  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

That message is there for a purpose I'm afraid. Easily said, you cannot get rid of this easily.

Comment: thanks for your response but  we can achieve same in selenium using Java..so must be doable in Robot framework as well